# CSV to JSON file conversion

Tags: python, json, csv

I am facing some difficulties to convert my CSV file to JSON format:
My CSV are in the following order with TAB spaced where 'label' and 'tweet' are column name and with TAB spaced.

```
label                tweet
0                    I love you Sydney #Sydneycafeseige 
1                    Please do not use today as an excuse
```

But I like to convert data to the following JSON format ina JSON file

```
{"tweet": " I love you Sydney #Sydneycafeseige", "label": 0}
{"tweet": "Please do not use today as an excuse ", "label": 0}
{"tweet": "Outrage as bystanders", "label": 0}
{"tweet": "This man carries a gun ", "label": 0}
```

I tried to use this script but not working:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('D:\\datasets\\wazeed\\sts_gold_tweet.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('D:\\datasets\\wazeed\\file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("label","tweet")

reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile)

for row in reader:
  json.dump(row, jsonfile)
  jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @WazedAli, If you can edit your question and state precisely the problem with your latest attempt, we're more than willing to help.

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: @coldspeed, Reopening since OP has now provided some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

With these problems, if in doubt, you can use `csv.reader` directly, which offers more control when building your list of dictionaries. Then use `json.dump` in one call.

Here's a demo:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv, json

mystr = StringIO("""label\ttweet
0\tI love you Sydney #Sydneycafeseige
1\tPlease do not use today as an excuse""")

data = []

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        data.append({headers[0]: int(line[0]), headers[1]: line[1]})

with open('file.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(data, fout)

with open('file.json', 'r') as fin:
    d = json.load(fin)

print(d)

[{'label': 0, 'tweet': 'I love you Sydney #Sydneycafeseige'},
 {'label': 1, 'tweet': 'Please do not use today as an excuse'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It is working as you said. but would be possible to make output without barces  '[' and ']' staring and ending and also without 'comma' in between json array.